# How do I store data inside a div tag into database?

Tags: jquery, html, database

I'm using a jquery like this http://www.jque.re/plugins/forms-controls/quick.tag/ to create quicktags. The quicktags are stored in a series of div tags like so

```
<div id="taglist">
    <div class="tag">
        <a class="close">x</a>
        Red
    </div>
    <div class="tag">
        <a class="close">x</a>
        Blue
    </div>
    <div class="tag">
        <a class="close">x</a>
        Green
   </div>
</div>
```

How will I be able to use the values of "Red" "Blue" and "Green" to insert into database? Sorry I'm new to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You need to use javascript to get the data from divs you want and you will need  server side language like PHP as well

2- While you tagged Jquery I assume you included it in html `<head>` or before `</body>`

3- how can you use jquery?? see next example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var arrayofcolors = [];
  $('#taglist > .tag').each(function(){
    var thisColor = $(this).text().replace('x' , '').trim().toLowerCase();
     arrayofcolors.push(thisColor);
  });
  alert(arrayofcolors);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="taglist">
    <div class="tag">
        <a class="close">x</a>
        Red
    </div>
    <div class="tag">
        <a class="close">x</a>
        Blue
    </div>
    <div class="tag">
        <a class="close">x</a>
        Green
   </div>
</div>
```

about passing arrayofcolors to php and save it into database you need to use `$.ajax()` method  .. and use it like

```
$.ajax(function(){
  url : 'to your php url here',
  method : 'POST',
  data : {arrayofcolors : arrayofcolors},
  success : function(data){
    // returned data from php file
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

in you php file

```
<?php
  echo $_POST['arrayofcolors'];
?>
```

this steps will return the alert with your colors

Comment: not using the php part but this is exactly what i need, thanks!